# Inplace of python executable inside virtual environment, getting Alias

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I was running an old python version of python 3(3.5.2), and because of that, some of the libraries(like the seaborn) were misbehaving. I tried upgrading python to 3.9 with the help of brew and was successfully able to do that. I can now see python inside the `/usr/local/bin/python3.9`. I also upgraded the pip and **virtualenv** package. After that, I unlink `/usr/local/bin/python` and then linked it with `/usr/local/bin/python3.9`. Next, I set alias in ~/.bash_profile to `/usr/local/bin/python`.
After performing the above process, `python -V` gives the new python(ie python 3.9).

But, when I now create the **virtualenv** with the command -

**`virtualenv nvenv --python=/usr/local/bin/python`**

the virtual environment is created but inside `nven/bin/` I could see an alias of the python3.9 and not the executable(like I had in my old virtual environment).

I tried with the following commands too but the result was same -

**`virtualenv nvenv`**

**`python -m virtualenv nvenv`**

I have performed so many steps without really understanding much and now I am confused now where I am going wrong. Could anyone help me to create the **virtualenv** with my latest python3.9 which also has python3.9 executable inside `bin` of it? I need it to set interpreter in the spyder IDE.

Comment: Be aware ``python`` is meant to denote Python*2* – ``python3`` is the proper name for Python3 in MacOS. ``python`` should only point to Python3 inside a venv.

Comment: Hi @MisterMiyagi. Thanks. I think I must have linked python to python 3.9 as when I run python -V, it shows Python 3.9.2

Comment: Yes, that is what you describe. I am just noting that this is *not* a standard setup – you might want to roll that back.

Comment: ``venv`` uses symlinks by default on purpose on MacOS. Have you tried the ``--copies`` flag to enforce copying?

Comment: This is great @MisterMiyagi. Now I can see the executables. So, the alias isn't really anything wrong, right? From what I understood, it is a way to not create unnecessary copies(correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: Also I might need to fix some more things now because python -V gives python 3.9 and python3 gives the old 3.5.2 @MisterMiyagi